# How to compose multipart MIME mixed message to display it correctly in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, mime-types, mime, mime-message

I am using java code to compose and send e-mail messages to MS Outlook 365 accounts. 
The message is composed as following:

1. plain text part;
2. html part containing only table;
3. plain text part;
4. File attachment.

I expect that outlook displays part 1-3 as message body and the last part as attachment. Instead it displays only first part as message itself and puts the rest parts as separate attachments. 
I have played with different headers, but result is the same. Is it some feature of MS stack (exchange, outlook, etc.) or I did something wrong?

The raw message is here

```
Date: Mon, 5 Jun 2017 12:01:47 -0700 (PDT)
From: no-reply@example.com
To: consumer@example.com
Message-ID: <some id>
Subject: Test email
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_0_2350964.1496689307498"

------=_Part_0_2350964.1496689307498
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline

Content before table

------=_Part_0_2350964.1496689307498
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline

<html><body><table><tr><td>First parameter</td><td>value</td></tr><tr><td>Second row</td><td>42</td></tr></table></body></html>
------=_Part_0_2350964.1496689307498
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline

This content should be placed after table

------=_Part_0_2350964.1496689307498
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
    name="report.xls"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report.xls"

0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOwADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
<skipped>
------=_Part_0_2350964.1496689307498--
```

As a result I see only "Content before table" line, two attachments like "ATT01.html" and "ATT02.txt" and my original attachment "report.xls".

I have found one related topic at some forum saying that this problem should not appear since Outlook 2010 or so, but I can see it in the latest version both in desktop app and the web application.
The workaround solution to put everything in html part requires more work, because text parts are generated by other components.

Answer (score 1):

On investigation, it appears that Outlook 365 handles multipart/mixed by treating the first part as the email and the rest as attachments.

This is *technically* a "road-legal" behaviour: the [relevant RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2046#section-5.1.3) only states that multipart/mixed "is intended for use when the body parts are independent and need to be bundled in a particular order".  Most email clients interpret this to mean that the parts are all inline subsections of a single document - especially webmail clients for whom this interpretation comes naturally - but, however strong the consensus, it's not outright stated as such in this RFC.

More dubiously, though, this treatment applies even if you use `Content-Disposition: inline`; Outlook does not appear to respect [the RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2183#section-2.1) here.  For example, in the following minimal example, only the "Testing 123" will appear inline:

```
Subject: Testing email
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="--bound--"
MIME-Version: 1.0

----bound--
Content-Disposition: inline

Testing 123

----bound--
Content-Disposition: inline

Testing 456
```

One rather extreme solution is to move hosting to a Microsoft Exchange server.  Per [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/mixed-ing-it-up-multipart-mixed-messages-and-you/ba-p/585841) from 2011, when using multipart/mixed, Exchange takes the industry-consensus interpretation of plain-text and HTML parts as representing inline sections of the message body, and conveys this structure to Outlook over MAPI.

Other than this, the only solution appears to be to "manually" merge the displayable email parts into a [single part](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/mixed-ing-it-up-multipart-mixed-messages-and-you/ba-p/585841) - something like:

```
Date: Mon, 5 Jun 2017 12:01:47 -0700 (PDT)
From: no-reply@example.com
To: consumer@example.com
Message-ID: <some id>
Subject: Test email
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_0_2350964.1496689307498"

------=_Part_0_2350964.1496689307498
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline

<html><body>
Content before table
<table><tr><td>First parameter</td><td>value</td></tr><tr><td>Second row</td><td>42</td></tr></table>
This content should be placed after table
</body></html>

------=_Part_0_2350964.1496689307498
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
    name="report.xls"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report.xls"

0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOwADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
<skipped>
------=_Part_0_2350964.1496689307498--
```

Note: I'm not sure this is the *same* problem you were having back in 2017, since the current behaviour seems to have [emerged in mid-2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73281975/mime-multipart-emails-how-do-i-persuade-microsoft-clients-to-show-two-html-or).  But it's definitely *a* problem that would affect anyone trying to do something similar in 2023.  (Based on personal testing against Microsoft 365 Outlook version 2306 build 16529.20182 C2R).)

In particular, it's apparently why my email chains - bouncing between the Samsung Email app on my phone and Outlook - keep losing their history: anything prior to the current email in the chain gets treated as an HTML attachment by Outlook and then discarded on hitting Reply.  Joy...

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping the parts incorrectly. It must be

```
1. Outer message, multipart/mixed
  2. multipart/related
    2.a text/plain
    2.b text/html
  3. attachment.
```