# MIME multipart emails: how do I persuade Microsoft clients to show two HTML (or even plain) parts?

Tags: email, mime, multipart

Executive summary: I can construct a multipart message which contains HTML in two separate parts, and it displays correctly in multiple MUAs. However, outlook.com insists on putting any additional HTML after the first HTML part in a downloadable attachment, instead of displaying it. It also does this for plaintext parts.

In detail: I need to add a signature to an email message, where the structure of the original message is, in general, unknown. I do this by wrapping the original message in a `multipart/mixed`, and then adding a new `multipart/alternative` which contains text and html versions of the required signature.

If the original message was itself a `multipart/alternative`, then the new message now looks like:

- multipart/mixed

  - multipart/alternative [the original message]

    - text/plain
    - text/html
  - multipart/alternative [the appended signature]

    - text/plain [plaintext signature]
    - text/html [html signature]

This displays well in various clients (Thunderbird, and webmail from gmail/Yahoo/AOL/gmx), showing the original message with the appended signature. However, it doesn't work for MS clients (I've only tried outlook.com). The two alternative signatures are presented to the user as *attachments*, and not inline, so the user only sees download boxes.

To get around this, I've historically done this for Microsoft:

- multipart/mixed

  - multipart/alternative [the original message]

    - text/plain
    - text/html
  - text/html [html-only signature]

This worked for several years for Microsoft, but has now stopped working - the signature is again shown as an attachment.

I've spent some hours experimenting with this, and can't find any way to get outlook.com to show two different HMTL (or even plain) text parts in the same message. The second one always appears as an attachment. Some of the things I've tried are:

- Replace the second `multipart-alternative` above with another `multipart/mixed`, which encloses the `multipart-alternative` signature
- Trying to force `Content-Disposition: inline` for the signature: this never works, and MS appears to ignore `Content-Disposition`
- Replace the outer `multipart/mixed` with `multipart-related`, with `type=multipart/alternative`

Any ideas on how I can get MS clients to actually show the signature, short of parsing the internals of the original message and re-writing it?